# Computing orbits of conjugacy classes in GAP.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gap

I have an extension group $G=N{.}Q$ ,  $N$ nonabelian. How do I compute the orbits of  $Q$ on the conjugacy classes of $N$  in GAP?  For example, take G=$S_5=A_5{:}2$. The Gap input "Orbits$(2,A_5)$ will give  33 orbits  of $C_2$ on the elements of $A_5$. How do I compute the orbits of $C_2$ on the  classes of $A_5$ in GAP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have the group $G$ given concretely with a normal subgroup $N$, you could do so by defining your own function for the action (such functions always take an element $\omega$ of the domain and a group element $g$ and return $\omega^g$:

```
OnConjugacyClasses:=function(class,g)
  return ConjugacyClass(ActingDomain(class),Representative(class)^g);
end;
```

With this, you can then calculate orbits as usual. In your example:

```
gap> G:=SymmetricGroup(5);;
gap> N:=DerivedSubgroup(G);;
gap> cl:=ConjugacyClasses(N);
[ ()^G, (1,2)(3,4)^G, (1,2,3)^G, (1,2,3,4,5)^G, (1,2,3,5,4)^G ]
gap> OrbitsDomain(G,cl,OnConjugacyClasses);
[ [ ()^G ], [ (1,2)(3,4)^G ], [ (1,2,3)^G ], [ (1,2,3,4,5)^G, (1,2,3,5,4)^G ]
 ]
```

If you try so for larger groups, it might be faster, to also transfer information about the centralizer of the representative, if known:

```
OnConjugacyClasses:=function(class,g)
local cl;
  cl:=ConjugacyClass(ActingDomain(class),Representative(class)^g);
  if HasStabilizerOfExternalSet(class) then
    SetStabilizerOfExternalSet(cl,StabilizerOfExternalSet(class)^g);
  fi;
  return cl;
end;
```

Comment: In addition, how will I do the action of the centralizer C_Q(g) on a coset Ng in GAP.

Comment: That would be a separate question, and you probably should specify how the subgroup of the factor is supposed to act on the elements of the coset.